# SimpleFramwork ByteArray Parsing

Tags: android, xml, image, simple-framework

I'm working on an android app. What I'm trying to do is to exchange images via Rest to my backend and return it later from there. At this point I managed to implement the create functionality to create the necessary object... serialize it with the SimpleFramwork... and store it via Hibernate to the Database.

Now, When I'm trying to get data from the backend I'm getting a deserializing Failure saying

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "321321321......
```

at the image attribute

I’m kind of confused because the field I’m using is a byte[].

```
@Element(required=false)
Private byte[] image;
```

Does anybody know why I get here this Integer problem ?
Thanks in forecast..
Spanky

Comment: Whats the stack trace...

Comment: Agreed, stacktrace and some more code / informations would be useful.